# How to get rid of a white space line in C?

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace

I'm a beginner and just learning structures in C, but I encountered a small problem. This is the code:

```c
struct Phone{
    char name[50];
    double screensize;
    int memory;
    int camera;
};

int main(){

    struct Phone phone1;
    printf("What model do you have? ");
    fgets(phone1.name,50, stdin);
    printf("How many MP does the camera have? ");
    scanf(" %d", &phone1.camera);
    printf("How much memory does you phone have? ");
    scanf(" %d", &phone1.memory);

    printf("You entered you have: \n");
    printf("Model: %s \nCamera: %d \nMemory: %d", phone1.name, phone1.camera, phone1.memory);
}
```

It doesn't have any errors but, when I run it and input my stuff, the last `printf` from the code will display the model name, a line of white space, and then the camera and memory on consecutive rows. I want to get rid of that line of white space. I tried to leave a white space in `scanf` before all `%d` in order to discard that line, but it doesn't work (I've read that `scanf` reads the newline when you input something first and, to prevent that, we just need to add a space to flush the buffer first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you input a line from console:

```
printf("What model do you have? ");
fgets(phone1.name,50, stdin);
```

it captures also a `'\n'` character, and then you print:

```
printf("Model: %s \nCamera: %d \nMemory: %d", phone1.name, phone1.camera, phone1.memory);
//             ^  ^ there you print that '\n' in phone1.name and second hardcoded
```

Comment: Oh damn. I understand now. I fixed it and it looks beautiful now. Thank you so much.